# Rails Associtions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Firm
has_many :clients

Client
belongs_to :firm # w Forign key firm_id

I can do client.firm.name

my question:

what is the best way to find clients that belong to this firm in the same format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all of the client objects, just do...

```
c = firm.clients
```

To get all of the client names for a firm as an array of strings, do...

```
names = firm.clients.all.collect {|c| c.name}
```